# python-docx, access to paragraph font-size

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I want to access to a paragraph or run that has a unique font or font-size using python-docx. How i can get texts of runs or paragraphs that has specified font or font-size?

Comment: Does this worked? for me the code returns None from the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any one that want to know:

```
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        if run.font.size == Pt(16):
            print(paragraph.text)
```

Comment: This code returns None for me. Any suggestions?\

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76650844/find-all-the-texts-which-is-normal-style-and-font-size-is-not-11-in-a-docx-fil/76651650#76651650)

Answer (score -1):

```
# Import the docx module
import docx

# Specify the path to the Word document
path = 'sample.docx'  # Document path

# Open the Word document
doc = docx.Document(path)

# Initialize an empty list to store font sizes
font_sizes = []

# Iterate over each paragraph in the document
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    # Iterate over each run (text with the same formatting) within the paragraph.
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        # Retrieve the font size of the run and append it to the font_sizes list
        font_size = run.font.size.pt
        font_sizes.append(font_size)

# Print the font sizes used in the document
print("Font Sizes used:", font_sizes)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your first contribution. Your answer is very similar to the previous accepted answer, although I appreciate the comments and import statement. Also, your answer returns a list of font sizes. The OP asked for a list of texts (with certain font or certain font size).