# Find all the texts which is 'Normal' style and font size is NOT 11 in a docx file using python-docx

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

My implementation so far:

```
from docx.api import Document
import pandas as pd
from docx.shared import Pt

texts = []
sizes = []
document = Document('new.docx')
for p in document.paragraphs:
    for run in p.runs:
        if p.style.name.startswith("Normal") and run.font.size != Pt(11):
            texts.append(run.text)
print(texts)
```

This seems to give the output but some outputs are incorrect. By incorrect I mean I am also getting output which is Normal style and font size is 11. Is this the correct implementation or is there any other way to achieve this? TIA!

Comment: @DarkKnight My output is the list 'texts'. The reason I am testing each run is that I want a particular run in a paragraph if it is Normal and not font size 11. Is there a better way please suggest.

Comment: If the style name is not Normal then there's no point in enumerating the runs. That's just an efficiency issue. I cannot see why your code would not work otherwise. You may need to ask the author(s) of docx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

What I learned is that styles are stored in another part of the .docx files by default. A style setting can be extracted in one condition. If that setting **differs** from the default style settings (e.g., Normal, No Spacing, Heading 1, Title, etc.) applied to the paragraph. In this case, Word stores it **with** the text.

Another StackOverflow question thread for a better understanding:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75601802/get-default-font-size-of-an-empty-document-in-python-docx)

### Example

E.g., If your Word's default font size for the *"Heading 1"* is 20pt, and your text is 20pt, you won't be able to extract it. But if it is something else, it will return by your code.